# Is there a simple tool for adding users to a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I'm looking for a simple tool, preferably one that I can redistribute with my application,  that **non-technical end-users** can use to add users (and logins if necessary) to a particular SQL Server (Express) database.

Obviously SSME will do the job, but I don't want to require users to install something so heavy-weight.

I have a good idea how I would write this myself using SQL Management Objects, but **I'm looking for something pre-built**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I wouldn't expect you to be able to find such a tool - the scope of it is too narrow - you want something with the power to create and edit Logins/Users, but be simple enough for laymen. Would you want such a powerful tool in the hands of such people? Apart from SSMS, there will be a number of 3rd Party clients for SQL Server, but you need something simple to use and locked down - I just don't see it happening.

However, I might be wrong - just because I haven't come across such a thing, it doesn't mean they don't exist.

I don't see why you can't build simple features into your application to add new users/logins. It seems the most sensible suggestion. Apart from SMO, is there any reason why you couldn't use CREATE LOGIN/CREATE USER T-SQL commands?

[Create User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

[Create Login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can write you own tool using the managed .NET Libraries [SQL Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms162169.aspx) (short SMO). They are shipped with .NET Framework 2.0 i think. So it should be no problem with dependencies.

SMO gives you full control over SQL Server. MS SQL Server Management Studio is also written based on these libraries.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of SMO; in fact they don't ship with .Net 2.0, you have to install them seperately. But as I have now emphasised in the question - I'm hoping that such a common tool will already be available.

Answer (score 1):

edit: There is nothing, from what I can see.  People normally build it into their application.